# node-red node with multiple outputs but send msgs asynchron

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-red

Can I send msgs to the outputs asynchron?

Like this with e.g. four outputs:

```
this.on('input', function(msg) {
    this.send([ msg, null, null, null ]);

    /* do some time consuming work */

    this.send([ null, msg, null, null ]);

    /* do some time consuming work */

    this.send([ null, msg, msg, null ]);

    /* do some time consuming work */

    this.send([ null, msg, null, null ]);

    /* do some time consuming work */

    this.send([ msg, msg, msg, msg ]);
});
```

When I do it like this, all the msg sends are queued and send when the input callback is done.

EDIT:
I mean node-red, not node-redis. 
The problem I have is, that all the sends are queued and not send directly. So during the input callback, I get no msgs at the outputs. When the input callback ends, all the msgs which where queued are pumped out at once.

What I want to have is, that a send directly sends the msg not waiting for the end of the input callback. So having asynchron output.

Hope this explains it better.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. When you say node-red do you mean [this node-red](https://github.com/node-red/node-red) or do you mean node-redis? What exactly is your question? What error do you get? What behaviour do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Problem solved!

Only the Debug Tab in the node-red GUI is the slow part. The debug output nodes set to "debug-tab and console" shows all message directly on the console!